# Derivative of Discrete Fourier Transform in Matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

this is a part of an assignment for a Fourier-Analysis course.

In this assignment I was asked to implement a matlab function to compute the derivative of a discrete function using the derivative of the Discrete Fourier Transform. The formula I was given was this formula:

[image]

The code I wrote is this, using 513 datapoints from -pi to pi:

```
t = -pi + ((2*pi)/513)*(0:513-1);
for n = 1:513
    tmpsum = 0;
    for k = 1:N
        tmpsum = tmpsum + (1i*k*fft(g(k))*exp(1i*k*n));
    end 
    deriv(n) = real((1/sqrt(N))*tmpsum);
end
```

It executes fine, but once I plot it against t (e.g. for g = sin(t)) I get a really weird graph, with spikes up to 2000 on the y axis.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
This is the code I currently run:

```
N = 512;
t = -pi + ((2*pi)/(N))*(0:N-1);
f = sin(t);
deriv = zeros(1,length(t));

ffft = fft(f);
for n = 1:N
    tmpsum = 0;
    for k = 1:N
        tmpsum = tmpsum + ((1i*k*ffft(k))*exp(1i*k*n));
    end 
    deriv(n) = (1/sqrt(N))*tmpsum;
end

plot(t,f,t,deriv);
```

Comment: SO is not for doing homework, but i would think that fft(g(k)) as you write it is maybe not what was meant in the formula you posted.

Comment: `fft(g(k))` computes the FFT of a single element.  That will definitely not do what you're expecting.  You need to compute the FFT of the **entire sequence**, then access each element in the result instead.  Something like `fg = fft(g);` outside of the `for` loop, then change `fft(g(k))` to `fg(k)` inside the `for` loop

Comment: @AlexanderKemp I was under the impression, that HW problems were okay on SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions . Thank you for your hint.

Comment: @rayryeng Okay, thank you! I will try this. Makes sense.

Comment: It is still not really working. Would I have to choose the number of datapoints (513 atm) to be the same as N? Since when I initialize a function as sin(t) and take the fft of this function, it will also have 513 datapoints.

Comment: @Felix90 Yes the number of points should be the same... can you show us the full code? This is only a portion that performs the transform.  Where is the signal defined, etc.?

Comment: (i) you should be using 512 points, not 513 (remember that the FFT is periodic), (ii) you should just compute the FFT first, then (complex) multiply each term by `ik` to get the derivative in the frequency domain.

Comment: Thank you both for all the help, I really appreciate it a lot! @rayreng I edited my current code into the question.

Comment: @PaulR I already feel bad for asking, since both you and rayryeng already helped so much, but do you (or anyone else) maybe have some more thoughts on the code I edited into the question? Thank you again!

Comment: I don't get why you're summing in the frequency domain ? You should just be multiplying each term in the frequency domain by the appropriate factor (`ik`) so that when you subsequently apply an ifft to get back to the time domain you have the derivative. Are you sure you understand the underlying math ? If not then you need to get that straight first.

Comment: @PaulR I guess I don't understand it as well as I thought and I will read up better on it. Still thank you so much for your help, it definitely helped me grasp the concept better (and show me where to research further). I appreciate it!

Comment: The important thing is to understand what happens in the frequency domain when you take the derivative in the time domain. Note that the derivative of `exp(j*k*x)` is `j*k*exp(j*k*x)`.